# Split large file, have arbitrary start index number

Tags: command-line

I do a lot of file manipulation on my system and in one particular batch job I end up with around 16 Gb file. I need to prepare this data into smaller chunks for another process.

I split it into 10k lines per file and numeric index, padded to 5 digits

```
split -a 5 -d -l 10000 large_input_file /out_path/out.
```

This way I end up with files named
out.00000
out.00001
...

The problem is that this way indexing always starts with 0.
Is there a way to set it to arbitrary starting index? man reveals nothing ...

Comment: Why do you want to start counting the chunk filenames from a non-zero index? Knowing the use case would help to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big deal to renumber the files afterwards.

```
split -a 5 -d -l 10000 large_input_file /out_path/tmp.
for x in /outpath/tmp.*; do
  mv -i -- "$x" "${x%/*}/out.$(printf %05d $((10#${x##*.}+1)))";
done
```

Note a couple of pitfalls:

- The naive approach of renaming `out.00000` to `out.00001` and so on doesn't work, because globbing expands to a lexicographically ordered list, so the first renaming would overwrite the second file. In zsh, you can use the `(On)` glob qualifier. In other shells, the easiest way is to change the stem of the name as well.
- A leading `0` in shell arithmetic causes the number to be interpreted in octal. `10#${…}` forces a decimal interpretation.
- `printf %05d` is a way to maintain the padding to 5 digits.

Comment: nice, and by replacing +1 with +$start_id I get arbitrary first index ...

Comment: btw. what is the meaning of -- in mv command? Can't seam to find it ... probably "no more switches after this point", right?

Comment: @nEJC: Yes, that's exactly it. In this particular case, it's not necessary, because the arguments can't begin with `-`, but it's a good habit to get into (and it's a reflex with me).

Answer (score 0):

I think this option doesn't exist in split. I've this bug (feauture request) for coreutils -- http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?22231